# Need help in debugging of specific weird issue of null object reference error on an EditText object Android

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

I'm aware about general case of java.lang.NullPointerException, but need help in debugging of this specific case. Please look: I have connected my layout editText with my Java class EditText but still gets an error while trying to get the text from the text field.

I still see this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object 
reference
```

and here is my code.
                                                                                     at com.ramadanapps.android.fireapp.Register.createUser(Register.java:56)

```
package com.ramadanapps.android.fireapp;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private EditText mEmail;
private EditText mPassword;
private Button mRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signUpEmail);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.singUpPassword);
    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createUser();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null){
        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Already signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void createUser() {
    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
    String password =  mPassword.getText().toString();

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class ));
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]}
```

I don't know where is the problem.

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ramadanapps.android.fireapp.Register">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/signUpEmail"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:hint="Email" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/singUpPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/signUpEmail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:hint="Password" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:id="@+id/signUpBtn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml has the id signUpEmail and I don't still know where the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure there is an edittext in your xml with the id `signUpEmail`? Post your xml too, also mark line number 56 by adding comment on it.

Comment: can you post activity_register.xml?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed your code on my side with only 2 differences:
1. I use my own firebase DB
2. My MainActivity is different - actually I created empty one just for testing.

The app works fine - I successfully signed-up several times with diffeent (fake) mails and passwords. Everytime I was passed to main activity, and when pressed "back"  - successfully moved back to Register activity. (snapshot attached).

No failures so far.
When I failed - it is when tried to sign-up on empty fields of mail or password - it's expected, you need validate the form.

Other possible reason of failure that comes in my mind - is in your main activity. May be there in onStart or onCreate methods you refer to non-defined TextViews? Would you like to share it with corresponding XML?

Thanks and good luck! ))

[image]